How to build datapipeline in Snowflake between tables and secure views
Secured views are available in the below different databases ans schemas.
SALE_UAT.SALE_SCH
FIN_UAT.FIN_SCH
FIN_UAT.MDM_SCH
PROD_UAT.PRD_SCH

Now we need to create dimension and fact tables in TRADEDEV_DB using views.
And build datapipelines to refresh fact and dimension tables.
I have followed the following approach to create datapipelines.
Step 1: Set Up the Fact and Dimension Tables
Create the target tables that will hold the data from the secure views
CREATE OR REPLACE TABLE TRADEDEV_DB.TRADEDEV_SCH.DIM_CUST AS
SELECT * FROM cust_view WHERE 1=0;

CREATE OR REPLACE TABLE TRADEDEV_DB.TRADEDEV_SCH.DIM_PROD AS
SELECT * FROM PROD_view WHERE 1=0;

Step 2: Create the Data Pipeline
Using streams (create streams on secure views) and tasks to automate the data refresh process.
But the views are having Left join, Group By and other operation so streams are not supporting.
We can't get the view definition to create Dynamic tables.
Could you please help me how to refresh the tables.
Thanks in advance.

Hi Experts. Could you please help

You need to provide a lot more detail here.

Detail as in: 1) What's the exact error message you get when you try and create a stream on one of these views? 2) What happens if you try and create a dynamic table as SELECT * from view 3) Do the views include a "high-water mark" column, such as a last updated date or incrementing key, that would allow you to implement a delta extract mechanism? 4) Please show the Table definitions (DDL) which will then also give us the source view structures
